# Using create-react-app hosted on S3 to hit a Heroku API

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-cloudfront, create-react-app

### Backgroud

The **backend** is a Rails API-only app running on Heroku (on port `5000` during local development).

The **frontend** is made with `create-react-app` and is hosted in an S3 bucket behind AWS CloudFront (on port `3000` during local development).

### Development Setup

Locally, the frontend's `package.json` includes:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

This lets me run a Javascript command like…

```js
await fetch(`/someEndpoint`)
```

…and the development server running on `localhost:3000` forwards the response from `http://localhost:5000/someEndpoint`. This works great and my frontend processes the responses successfully .

### Production Issues

Now I'm running on production.

If I change nothing, the same line will try to load from `https://asdfasdfasdf.cloudfront.net/someEndpoint` which will 404.

Instead I want to configure the app so that in production it will hit the Heroku app `https://my-awesome-rails-app.herokuapp.com/someEndpoint` where the Rails API is running.

### Questions

(1) Is what I want possible without changing the code

```
await fetch(`/someEndpoint`)
```

either by configuring the frontend to use `my-awesome-rails-app.herokuapp.com`, or by configuring CloudFront to forward some requests to S3 and others to Heroku?

(2) If neither are possible, how should I write the `fetch()` command to let me hit Heroku in production but still keep the local proxying behavior during local development? Some use of environment variables maybe?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, It's better to follow the same process (to get the API hostname) in all the environments. Also setting up CloudFront only for this purpose is not convincing unless you have other reasons to do so.

I think you could use an environment variable and here is how you can do it.

#### using environment variables in react project

`react-scripts supports` environment variables using `dotenv` library.

we build the react app using:

```
REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN=REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN npm run build
```

or you can define a `.env.production` where the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`.

```
REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN=http://localhost:5000
```

Then in your code file, you can access it from `process.env`

```
await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN}/someEndpoint`)
```

Please read the reference, there is a pattern using which you should define the environment variables for it to work. for e.g each environment variable you define should start with `REACT_APP_`

Reference:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

hope this helps.